# WebCam Canvas - Zoom

Tags: javascript, html5, canvas, webcam

Existe alguma maneira, um comando que me permita alterar o zoom da WebCam ?
Nesse código abaixo é onde crio meu canvas da WebCam para Snapshot no site.

Eu quero aplicar - zoom, ou seja, aumentar a área de cobertura da Cam. É possível ?

```
    /* ACTIVE WEBCAM */
    if(!webCamActive)
    {
        webCamActive = true;
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia || navigator.oGetUserMedia;

        var vgacontraint = {
            video: {
                mandatory: {
                    maxWidth: 650,
                    maxHeight: 435
                }
            }
        };

        if(navigator.getUserMedia){
            navigator.getUserMedia(vgacontraint, function(stream){
                webCamVideo.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
                webCamVideo.play();
            }, function(e){
                console.log(e);
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Resolvido. Me afastei para tirar a foto. Obrigado.